# Convert inputstream to textfield.text objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, inputstream

I have some problem with my objective-c app. I want to convert input stream to `textfield.text` in objective-c.

I have tcp client with input stream and output stream. I want to use data from input stream and show them in uitextfield.

Can I use something like that:

```
temperatura.text = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];


- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            if (theStream == inputStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output) {

                            NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
```

I'm using this client. I want to use data from 'output' to get them on textfield.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Can you provide more details? What are you trying to do and what issue you are facing?

Comment: Show some code  what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Following line of code will return an int

> [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)]

Following line of code needs a NSString not int

> temperatura.text

So you will have to typecast `[inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)]` to a string before you assign to `temperatura.text` . You can use following to typecast:

```
temperatura.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)]];
```

A simple typecast example is :

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theinteger];
```

Please note that I have not tested this code for proper syntax, but this could be a solution. Let me know if you face any problems.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still hasn't seen the data from input stream. I must think for a while about it and i will ask then.

Comment: May be your textbox is not showing, try it with some dummy data, for ex: `temperatura.text = @"TestData";` and see if this text showsup

Comment: Ok something works ok, but not everything. It shows me the answer from input stream but not this one which i want to.         uint8_t buffer[1024];
    int len;
    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
     _temperatura.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you edit your original question and ask this followup question with proper format and details? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer Folowing Code

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {

  switch(eventCode) {

  ```
  case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

  {

      if(!_data) {

          _data = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

      }

      uint8_t buf[1024];

      unsigned int len = 0;

      len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:1024];

      if(len) {

          [_data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];

          // bytesRead is an instance variable of type NSNumber.

          [bytesRead setIntValue:[bytesRead intValue]+len];

      } else {

          NSLog(@"no buffer!");

      }

      break;
  ```

**

### temperatura.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[_data bytes] length:[_data length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

**